# Assign Unicode Literals to PowerShell Hash Table

Tags: powershell, unicode, encoding, unicode-literals

It's late and I am done for tonight--can someone please lend a hand on getting this to work? Do I need to do some additional work to get these Unicode strings assigned as literals?

First attempt at creating a hash table of double-encoded and desired key-value pairs:

```
[string] $double_encoded_values = @{
"â‚¬"   = "€";
"â€š"   = "‚";
"Æ’"    = "ƒ";
"â€ž"   = "„";
"â€¦"   = "…";
"â€"    = "†";
"â€¡"   = "‡";
"Ë†"    = "ˆ";
"â€°"   = "‰";
"Å"     = "Š";
"â€¹"   = "‹";
"Å’"    = "Œ";
"Å½"    = "Ž";
"â€˜"   = "‘";
"â€™"   = "’";
"â€œ"   = "“";
"â€"    = "”";
"â€¢"   = "•";
"â€“"   = "–";
"â€”"   = "—";
"Ëœ"    = "˜" ;
"â„¢"   = "™";
"Å¡"    = "š";
"â€º"   = "›";
"Å“"    = "œ";
"Å¾"    = "ž";
"Å¸"    = "Ÿ";
"Â¡"    = "¡";
"Â¢"    = "¢";
"Â£"    = "£";
"Â¤"    = "¤";
"Â¥"    = "¥";
"Â¦"    = "¦";
"Â§"    = "§";
"Â¨"    = "¨";
"Â©"    = "©";
"Âª"    = "ª";
"Â«"    = "«";
"Â¬"    = "¬";
"Â®"    = "®";
"Â¯"    = "¯";
"Â°"    = "°";
"Â±"    = "±";
"Â²"    = "²";
"Â³"    = "³";
"Â´"    = "´";
"Âµ"    = "µ";
"Â¶"    = "¶";
"Â·"    = "·";
"Â¸"    = "¸";
"Â¹"    = "¹";
"Âº"    = "º";
"Â»"    = "»";
"Â¼"    = "¼";
"Â½"    = "½";
"Â¾"    = "¾";
} # $double_encoded_values
```

My version:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

Error received:

```
At line:20 char:12
    + "â€“"   = "–";
    +            ~
    Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
    At line:20 char:12
    + "â€“"   = "–";
    +            ~
    The hash literal was incomplete.
        + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral
```

Reference: http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell treats the `“` in `â€“` as a double quote, effectively escaping the closing `"` in `"â€“"`

Use single quotes to avoid having PowerShell trying to parse the key names and values:

```
@{
    'â€“' = '-'
}
```